# Base url breaks relative URLS

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla1.7

I have a website with Joomla, for example this one:

http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakw

And it has base set to:

http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakw

And on top and left i have menus created in Joomla that have relative urls like:

/edukacja

And it seems that crawlers come to http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakw

and crawl the relative path using the base url and get:

http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakwedukacja

And when they go there base url changes to

http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakwedukacja

And crawler goes to:

http://polishwords.com.pl/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakwedukacjaedukacja

And so on.

So base url combined with related links to menu create a loop using standard Joomla.

I dont use any exts for SEF, and i dont want to. I use Joomla 1.7.5.

Am i doing something wrong? Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Now am a bit confused what the question is really ....

Comment: @Baba The question is how to break the loop. Plase specify what is unclear for you.

Comment: I am wondering, do human visitors also end up in a similar loop?

Comment: @Salman A Well... in fact no. It seems browser can handle it better than headless browser i suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Do not** use `base href`
2. Always use only **absolute** paths in your HTML

These 2 simple rules will solve every possible error related to links in HTML

> relative urls like: `/edukacja`

As a matter of fact, it's **absolute** path, but wrong one. You need to make your Joomla to make this path `/ksiazki/ksiazka/lihakw/edukacja` which would be a proper absolute path

Comment: well the proper path is polishwords.com.pl/edukacja. How to make Joomla use absolute paths for all menus than?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the system SEF plugin, it could be part of the solution.

Also, try updating to J2.5.9, it fixed several similar (but not identical) issues for me.